# Reordering divs with FadeIn - FadeOut effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `divs` that I want to reorder. This needs to be done with javascript/jquery as the values come from AJAX calls after the html has already been loaded.

I found several ways to do a simple reordering, but I want to add `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effects, so the user sees the actual reordering instead of just seeing `divs` suddenly disappearing and popping up.

[This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/J0ANMM/r49z4qnw/3/) has a simplified version of my code, without the `fadeOut` effect.

I then tried replacing

```
$(currentResult).remove();
$(currentResult).hide().insertBefore($(relevantResults[j])).fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

by:

```
$(currentResult).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function(){
      $(currentResult).hide().insertBefore($(relevantResults[j])).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

to get the desired effect. But nothing is inserted.

Any idea of how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(currentResult).hide('fast', function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(relevantResults[j])).show('fast');
});
```